# How to change macports default mirrors?

Tags: macports, osx-mountain-lion

I have a problem in here that default provided mirror connects about 15seconds for new package which I want to install.  Mirror url is: **http://mse.uk.packages.macports**

My question is how to change this uk mirror to my local one: Netherlands. I couldn't find this url in any macport configuration file. My osx default settings is UK, mainly choosed this one so that youtube dutch adds won't bother me anymroe.

Comment: Have you tried the rsync url in /opt/local/etc/macports/sources.conf or the rsync hostname in /opt/local/etc/macports/macports.conf

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as DanR stated in comment take a look at `/opt/local/etc/macports/sources.conf` file.

```
#  To get the ports tree from the master MacPorts server in California, USA use:
#      rsync://rsync.macports.org/release/ports/
#  To get it from the mirror in Trondheim, Norway use:
#      rsync://trd.no.rsync.macports.org/release/ports/
#  A current list of mirrors is available at https://trac.macports.org/wiki/Mirrors
```